# How to create a table with a dialog box using Impala UI of HUE?

Tags: hive, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, hue, impala

Following script can create a table with a dialog box asking user to input the TableName:

```
CREATE TABLE $TableName (name STRING);
```

Now I want to create a table with two inputs to concatenate them as a tablename.
I tried

```
CREATE TABLE $TableNamePrefix_$TableName (name STRING);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE concat($TableNamePrefix,"_",$TableName) (name STRING);
```

But neither works.

Any idea how to make a concatenated table name?

Answer (score 1):

Using curly brackets should work:

```
CREATE TABLE ${TableNamePrefix}_${TableName} (name STRING);
```